# Printing a pdf file on client side printer in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I have a problem in my project that i open a dynamically generated PDF file in popup window which working correctly. But now i want to print that pdf directly when popup is open at client side printer, how can i solved it ??

I need help of yours. Please suggest me some code for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This Code It will Work For You.

```
    Process printjob = new Process();

    printjob.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\R&D\Changes to be made.pdf" //path of your file;

    printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";

    printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();

    setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    printjob.Start();
```

Comment: If this is an asp.net site then this will print it on the server and not the client.

Comment: Be warned! This does not print on the client!

Answer (score 5):

You need to open the popup with javascript and the fire the `print()` function on it.

```
var opts = 'width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0';
var newWindow = window.open(yourUrl,'name',opts);
newWindow.print();
```

Note that the url you open must be in the same domain as your current page for this to work.

Comment: I tried this one also but it directly not print on client side's printer. It just open file in Popup window but not print automatically from Default Printer of Client Machine. I need to print that file automatically when popup open, Is there any way ??

Comment: Nope. You can only open the print dialog. Did it open the print dialog? It should do that. But you cannot force a print, that is a horrible idea. Imagine the attacks you could do with that, if that was possible the Internet would not be usable.

Comment: Yes it open the print dialog. But I want to give the feature that will  directly print that file from the printer so that The User does not need to click on Print Button, it directly print out when the file is open in Popup window. And It is possible i saw this type of feature in other projects. But i don't know how to do it ??

Comment: Nope. Not possible from a browser without an addon or something like that - not from your basic websites. Where have you seen this? I Really want to see it. Maybe you could do this if you had a browser plugin/addon or some ActiveX magic, but even that sounds unlikely and completely and utterly horrible. Imagine the horror if I could do that; I could just send links to some website to my "friends" and if they clicked, their printer would starting printing thousands of pages of marketing material (yeah ok, pictures of ponies).

Comment: Ya it is possible but i don't want to do any horrible things, I just want to give this facility when button is pressed and popup is open then only it will print. Check this link http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-PDF-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-default-printer-without-print-dialog/

Comment: No; it's not. In that page in the client requirements it lists "WebClientPrint Processor". In the code comment: "WCPP utility is installed at the client side". Meaning a simple basic browser cannot do it, clients will need to install an addon. Or do you want to create a similar addon? Or do you want to use that addon if the client has it? If so, you should ask that instead.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to install that utility in Client machine, already i have installed this in system at client side but then also it will not work and give me the error "Status Code : 500" for this i want a solution how to solve this error. Can you please help me with the use of this WCPP utility ??